# JSON Parsing PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have the following JSON format:

```
"also_known_as" : [ "Superman" ],
"business" : { "copyright_holder" : [ [ "Copyright MCMXLII Walt Disney Productions (on print)",
              " Walt Disney Productions",
              " 28 February 1942",
              " LP12270 (in copyright registry)"
            ] ]
```

So I'm able to parse to get the "also_known_as" section using:

```
$json_a = json_decode($THE_API_URL);

foreach($json_a as $mydata) {
echo  $mydata->also_known_as[0]
}
```

However can't get the date in the copyright_holder section i.e. "28 February 1942". Could someone please help me with the syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($json_a)` to see exactly what's going on, and then it is PHP 101.

Comment: That's not exactly valid JSON.

Comment: I was just giving a sample of the JSON. Will try the var_dump.

Comment: Assuming this JSON string is just a sample and the actual one is correct, I believe you should be able to access it in your loop using `$mydata->business->copyright_holder[0][2]`.

Comment: Cheers Travest3, that was it: $mydata->business->copyright_holder[0][2]

Comment: @SaeUs: Yep, sorry, had an extra arrow in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for more information.

You can also double check that the json string is correctly formatted. The string you posted does not properly json_decode.

As Jon said, once you get it decoded, simply var_dump the unserialized json array to see if everything went through correctly.

You can also view JSON online with http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for that second link exactly what I need to visualise/learn.